# How do I open multiple tabs in IE instead of multiple windows using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

I am using selenium Java. I need to open Multiple tabs and open different URL's in the newly opened tab. I am try to using `getWindowHandles()`, It is not working for Internet Explorer. Please suggest the proper solution for this.

Here is the code I have used:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Multiple 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");       
        WebDriver d = new InternetExplorerDriver();     
        d.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
        //d.switchTo().window(d.getWindowHandles().iterator().next());                                  
        ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (d.getWindowHandles());
        d.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));          
        d.get("https://www.facebook.com/login");                        
    }
}
```

Using above code I'm able to open new tab but second URL is not entering.
Can any one give me the perfect solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait, maybe it's not switching fast enough before it's trying to navigate to the facebook url?

Comment: Is `sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t")` working? How can you be sure that `d.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));` is the `New Tab`?

Comment: I  tried with wait also,but it is not working